# PHPunit: How to mock a method that has a parameter AND a returned value

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Using PHPUnit, I wonder if we can mock an object to test if a method is called with an expected parameter, **and** a returned value?

In the [doc](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects), there are examples with passing parameter, or returned value, but not **both**...

I tried using this:

```
// My object to test
$hoard = new Hoard();
// Mock objects used as parameters
$item = $this->getMock('Item');
$user = $this->getMock('User', array('removeItem'));
...
$user->expects($this->once())
     ->method('removeItem')
     ->with($this->equalTo($item));
$this->assertTrue($hoard->removeItemFromUser($item, $user));
```

**My assertion fails** because Hoard::removeItemFromUser() should return the returned value of User::removeItem(), which is true.

```
$user->expects($this->once())
     ->method('removeItem')
     ->with($this->equalTo($item), $this->returnValue(true));
$this->assertTrue($hoard->removeItemFromUser($item, $user));
```

Also fails with the following message: "**Parameter count for invocation User::removeItem(Mock_Item_767aa2db Object (...)) is too low.**"

```
$user->expects($this->once())
     ->method('removeItem')
     ->with($this->equalTo($item))
     ->with($this->returnValue(true));
$this->assertTrue($hoard->removeItemFromUser($item, $user));
```

Also fails with the following message: "**PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Parameter matcher is already defined, cannot redefine**"

What should I do to test this method correctly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use `will` instead of `with` for `returnValue` and friends.

```
$user->expects($this->once())
     ->method('removeItem')
     ->with($item)  // equalTo() is the default; save some keystrokes
     ->will($this->returnValue(true));    // <-- will instead of with
$this->assertTrue($hoard->removeItemFromUser($item, $user));
```

Answer (score 6):

I know that it's an old post, but it's on the top in searching for PHPUnit warning **Method name matcher is already defined, cannot redefine**, so I'll answer too.

There is other reason for such warning message. If you describe a mock behaviour in chaining method like this:

```
$research = $this->createMock(Research::class);
$research->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getId')
    ->willReturn(1)
    ->method('getAgent')
    ->willReturn(1);
```

You will get warning **Method name matcher is already defined, cannot redefine**. Just split it in separate statements and the warning will go away (tested on PHPUnit 7.5 and 8.3).

```
$research = $this->createMock(Research::class);

$research->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getId')
    ->willReturn(1);

$research->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getAgent')
    ->willReturn(1);
```